# System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException during Sharepoint Server configuration wizard

Tags: windows, sharepoint, com-interop, windows-server-2016, sharepoint-2016

I've been following [this guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cKNdUzPWRBc) in order to install and configure my Sharepoint Server.

I've selected exacly the same configuration as he did:

1. Create new server farm
2. Single-Server Farm

But after clicking next in the "Configure Sharepoint Central Administration Web Application" this error pops up:

[image: The Error]

I've been trying to solve this problem using other questions from Sharepoint Wizard and Interop errors but none of them seem to work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone face the same problem. I've solved my issue by removing a FTP Site from my IIS. Any other misconfigured site will result in the same error.